# LinkedIn API returns 403 when requesting companies list

Tags: linkedin-api

We use the LinkedIn API to list companies that a user admins.

We have our App set to get r_fullprofile and rw_company_admin when the user grants permission.

We're trying to list all of the companies the user has admin access to via:
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies:(id,name,square-logo-url)?is-company-admin=true

```
<error>
    <status>403</status>
    <timestamp>1432323149224</timestamp>
    <request-id>XXXXXXXXXX</request-id>
    <error-code>0</error-code>
    <message>Member [user id] does not have permission to get companies as admin.</message>
</error>
```

According to the Manage Company Pages docs, as long as we have the rw_company_admin scope, we should be able to call this endpoint.

I've read through the Developer Program Transition docs (https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) but it doesn't seem to affect this usage of the API.

ETA:  This has been flagged as a possible duplicate of [LinkedIn API unable to view _any_ company profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409219/linkedin-api-unable-to-view-any-company-profile)

That question is about fetching details for a single company (which the user may or may not administrate).  My question is about listing companies that the user specifically does administrate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinkedIn API unable to view \_any\_ company profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409219/linkedin-api-unable-to-view-any-company-profile)

Answer (score 1):

According to new api changes user should be administrator of target company. Read this .

All calls to Companies API endpoints will require the authenticated user to be flagged as an administrator of the LinkedIn Company Page that is the target of the API call.  You become the administrator of a page when you create it.  If the page already exists, you will have to contact the existing administrator to grant admin access to other LinkedIn members.

Comment: The user in question is an admin of the companies I'm trying to list.

I can do a successful call to: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/[company id]

and receive a response:

`<company>
        <id>[company id]</id>
        <name>[company name]</name>
    </company>`

Comment: @CoryForseth  Did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same problem trying to get statistics for a company page I am managing

Comment: @Leon It's been a while but I believe it fixed itself.  Sorry I couldn't help more

Comment: @CoryForseth Same.  I didnt touch it and now it works.  LinkedIns API must be messed up

Comment: Does it mean that Normal User can not even fetch the public feeds of Company? via API?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and the problem was with the initial authorization code. You should mention the **scope=rw_company_admin** while doing the initial redirect URL call. Something like this -

*https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=**your_client_id**&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com/&state=12345&scope=**rw_company_admin**%20r_emailaddress%20w_share%20r_basicprofile*