# LinkedIn API unable to view _any_ company profile

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to figure out how to access *any* company profile on LinkedIn. For example, the [REST endpoint API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_profile) for LinkedIn itself is:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337?format=json
```

with the sample response of:

```
{
  "id": 1337,
  "name": "LinkedIn"
}
```

However, after authenticating with OAuth2 with `rw_company_admin` enabled, my app returns:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Member 206xxxxxx does not have permission to get company 1337",
  "requestId": "G6LNMCEZO8",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1432358171348
}
```

This worked up until very recently.

The documentation [does note that](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_profile) *"In order to perform any of the company page management API calls below, the authenticated LinkedIn user making the requests must be an administrator of the target company."* Confusingly, [it also says that](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) *"The following endpoints are the only ones that will remain available for use... Companies API — `/v1/companies/{id}`"*.

However, my goal isn't to manage a company as an admin, it's to show a user a brief output of the company. How can I get company info?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like they turned that feature off.

See https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

> **New requirement for Companies API**
>
> **All calls to Companies API endpoints** will require the authenticated
>   user to be flagged as an **administrator** of the LinkedIn Company Page
>   that is the target of the API call.  You become the administrator of a
>   page when you create it.  If the page already exists, you will have to
>   contact the existing administrator to grant admin access to other
>   LinkedIn members.
>
> Your API call will return a 403 Forbidden error if you do not have the
>   appropriate admin permission to interact with the target company.

And in the first line,

> On February 12th 2015 we announced a series of changes to our
>   developer program.  These changes have now begun to take affect and
>   will be rolled out to the entire LinkedIn application base between May
>   **12th - May 19th, 2015**.

So we are out of luck.

Comment: So you have to be the administrator of the company, _just to get info about the company_? I would assume that the company info is most useful to _people who **aren't** administrators_!

Comment: @Hooked : I agree and I am screwed as well. Maybe you can get the same information via Facebook API from the according facebook page ? (But I am not sure about the facebook API either they have a rather complicated rights system  too )

Comment: Note that you have to be added as an administrator of the *company page* not the developer application. Easy to miss.

Comment: Also if anyone had the same problem check to make sure you are searching by id(usually 7 letters) and not 'universal_name'.  Thats what caused it for me

Answer (score 6):

For accessing the company details from LinkedIn you must make a authenticated request(You must be the administrator of the company). For authenticated calls follow this link. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#!

Anyway, you must have the permission **rw_company_admin** to access the company details. For that, you must check Default Application Permissions in your App settings and also important to note that when you request for an Authorization Code you must specify the **scope**.

Use this method to get an authorization code for a company

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=987654321**&scope=rw_company_admin**

Comment: I tried this - **rw_company_admin**  yet its showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this as well even though I was definitely a company admin. Once I added that company as my current place of work on my profile, the API started to respond as expected.