# LinkedIn Followers Count produces error even after successful authentication

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I used the LinkedIn API to get the followers count of a page, but it resulted in the following error ;

GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/XXXX:(num-followers) 403 (Forbidden)

Object {errorCode: 0, message: "Member 0 does not have permission to get company xxxxx", requestId: "yyyyyyy", status: 403, timestamp: zzzzzzz}

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: That member doesn't have permission to do that GET.... This may [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409219/linkedin-api-unable-to-view-any-company-profile)

Comment: Thank you @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc for the link that clearly explain about the forbidden error.Even though the above said member i used in application does have admin permission for those companies, I still get the 403 error. could you please help me to sort it out?

Comment: You need to add access_token in the request parameter and make sure that you have permission to access company on linkedin end .