# Application authentication for linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there a way to make an authentication through application(not by the user)?

I want to show my company's status updates in my website and I don't  want users to log in to see the updates.

To make a request to companies API we [need access token generated through an administrator of the company page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409219/linkedin-api-unable-to-view-any-company-profile). I have administrator credentials for my company with me and I need a way to generate access token through application using server side scripting, so that I can display the status updates of the company in my website without asking user to log in.

I saw this [linkedin oAuth page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) and the step 2 indicates a redirect. Instead of redirect, if there is a way I could request for *code* parameter by sending the credentials and I am done, I can show the updates on my website.